# Javascript: resize base64 image and return string in non-async way

Tags: javascript

I googled enough examples and found solution how to resize images:

```
function imageToDataUri(img, width, height) {

    // create an off-screen canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // set its dimension to target size
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;

    // draw source image into the off-screen canvas:
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

    // encode image to data-uri with base64 version of compressed image
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}

function resizeImage() {
    var newDataUri = imageToDataUri(this, 10, 10); // resize to 10x10
    return newDataUri;
}
```

and this is my problem:

I have list of objects where each Item has based 64 image string: `group.mAvatarImgBase64Str`.  That string is greater then 10x10 and I need replace it with new String.

So far I did:

```
  if (group.mAvatarImgBase64Str !== 'none') {

            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = resizeImage;
            img.src = group.mAvatarImgBase64Str;
            // group.mAvatarImgBase64Str = ?? 
  }
```

If I'll print out new value in `resizeImage` method - It resized properly but:

**How do I add new String back to `group.mAvatarImgBase64Str`?**

`onload` task is async and I need something like:

```
 group.mAvatarImgBase64Str = resize(group.mAvatarImgBase64Str, 10, 10);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure this needs to be done via `onload`? Have you tried just calling `resizeImage` directly?

Comment: You have a list of larger than 10 x 10 images in base64 encoded format that you want to resize to 10 x 10 and have the result be base64 encoded as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it this way:

```
if (group.mAvatarImgBase64Str !== 'none') {

    (function(group) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            group.mAvatarImgBase64Str = resizeImage.call(this);
        }
        img.src = group.mAvatarImgBase64Str;
    })(group);

}
```

Additional IIFE is needed in case if you use for loop to iterate over array of object. If you use `forEach` loop, it's not needed.